# Is there a specific name for these methods of summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

When calculating summation of series I use these methods ;

Ex: **Method One** $$U_r=\frac{1}{(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

$$U_r=\frac{1}{(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)}\left[\frac{(r+2)-(r-1)}{3}\right]$$
Then 
$$U_r=\frac{1}{3(r-1)r(r+1)}-\frac{1}{3r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

Then clearly $$U_r=f(r)-f(r+1)$$

Ex: **Method Two**

$$U_r=(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)$$

$$U_r=(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)\left[\frac{(r+3)-(r-2)}{5}\right]$$

$$U_r=\frac{(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)}{5}-\frac{(r-2)(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)}{5}$$

Then clearly $$U_r=f(r)-f(r-1)$$

My question :

Is there a specific name for this method ?

*Most of the time I use "Method of finding $f(r)$ such that ..."

Comment: This is closely related to the Method of Partial Fractions.

Comment: @Travis no it is not ! In partial fraction , you would get four terms for $U_r$

Comment: The decomposition here is not the output of the Method of Partial fractions, but it is *closely related*...

Comment: Perhaps the term you are looking for is Telescoping? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series